# ASP.NET WebAPI JSON Binding Case-Sensitivity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net

Upgrading from ASP.NET WebAPI Beta to RC has provided some amount of excitement and a great deal of frustration.  I have been able to work through the majority of the issues, but the one that is biting me right now is case-sensitivity of JSON request data.

The formatter used for JSON requests (which by default is a JSON.NET formatter) appears to be case sensitive while the formatter used for form-urlencoded data does not.  Is there a way to configure the JSON requests to use a case-insensitive formatter?

Here is a simple example to illustrate the problem that I am having with JSON requests:

**HTML / JavaScript**

```
<button id="tester">Click here!</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tester").on("click", function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Api/Test/Index/" + 168,
                data: ko.toJSON({ key: 123, value: "test value" }), // THIS FAILS
                               // Key: 123, Value: "test value" <- BUT THIS WORKS
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                statusCode: {
                    200: function () {
                        $("body").append("<p>Success</p>");
                    },
                    400: function () {
                        $("body").append("<p>Failure</p>");
                    }
                }
            }).always(function () {
                $("body").append("<hr />");
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**C#**

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Index(int? id, KeyValuePair<int, string> test)
    {
        if (id != 168 || test.Key != 123 || test.Value != "test value")
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

I've provided a comment on the line where the JSON data is provided.  I would rather not break convention with my JavaScript objects by proper casing property members and I certainly do not want to break convention by lower casing my C# properties.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You send your data within a POST request - in other words, within a request body. But in the HTTP documentation it's said that header fields (and values) are considered case-insensitive, and there's nothing about the body... Why do you think "it's not the behaviour for form-urlencoded data", I wonder?

Comment: Check [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/soundcloudapi/browse_thread/thread/c266c0d2efa88fbb/9ad3969dde919cba), for example.

Comment: @raina77ow This isn't really a question about the HTTP specification but the behavior of JSON.NET formatter used by ASP.NET WebAPI RC.  The FormUrl formatter appears to be case-insensitive while the JSON.NET formatter *is* case-sensitive.

Comment: I think case-sensitivity is correct. Why would you need case-insensitivity while C# and JavaScript are both case-sensitive?

Comment: I realize that they are both case sensitive, but the value provider or formatter used for parameter binding does not need to be case-sensitive as evidenced by the behavior of form-urlencoded data. I'll update the question to reflect this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After digging into this issue in significant depth I came to realize that I was hitting a bug in the Json.NET KeyValuePair converter.  James Newton-King was kind enough to answer my related question and provided a link to the fix:

[Json.NET Case-insensitive Property Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266695/json-net-case-insensitive-property-deserialization)

Answer (score 25):

The Json.NET formatter is case insensitive for deserialization (json -> CLR).

On serialization, you can get camel casing by using the [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.htm).

In your Global.asax:

```
var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
json.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

Comment: I believed this to be the case, but I haven't been able to prove that behavior.  Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266695/json-net-case-insensitive-property-deserialization

Comment: Hmm ... I just did some experimenting with JsonConvert. Deserializing KeyValuePair<T> is case-sensitive, like you say, but if I create a POCO, the behavior is definitely case insensitive. Seems to be related to KeyValuePair having getters but no setters, because I defined my own version of KeyValuePair with setters and that worked.

Comment: Ah, you might be on to something ... I'll do some further experimenting and see if I can determine how it is deserializing with matching cased keys.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know whether the same is possible in XML? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835100/asp-net-web-api-xml-in-camelcase