# json to object, how should my object be like?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I have a json string like this

```
{ "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [ {"key":"CTR:2", "type":"Controller", "devicename":"ACU-1K", "imageUrl":"../../../../Images/ComputerSpeaker_32.png", "loc":"295 97"} ],
  "linkDataArray": [  ]}
```

I created a class like this

```
public class FloorplanItem
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public string[] NodeDataArray { get; set; }
    public string[] LinkDataArray { get; set; }        
}
```

I'm using newtonsoft.json to deserialize the json to an object but I'm getting some errors

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FloorplanItem>(json)
```

Error message:

```
{"Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'nodeDataArray[0]', line 2, position 23."}
```

I'm still pretty new to json, so please pardon me if this is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use http://json2csharp.com/. Copy the json there and you will get the following class:

```
public class NodeDataArray
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string devicename { get; set; }
    public string imageUrl { get; set; }
    public string loc { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string @class { get; set; }
    public List<NodeDataArray> nodeDataArray { get; set; }
    public List<object> linkDataArray { get; set; }
}
```

The above class will be compliant with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Great, didn't know there was such a tool. If you don't mind answering my comment, is json case sensitive? i.e., if my json property is devicename, but in my C# class, I have DeviceName, is that alright?

Comment: Not really sure, You can read about it here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266695/json-net-case-insensitive-property-deserialization and also can check it with a simple json in your code

Comment: JSON.NET is case insensitive by default. Alternatively, you can annotate your properties with an attribute: `[JsonProperty("overriddenPropertyName")]`

Answer (score 1):

**Your `NodeDataArray` is defined as an array of strings, while your JSON document clearly defines it as an object.**

Also, with [Web Essentials 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) you can perform a special paste called *Paste JSON As Classes* that will generate the desired CLR classes for you:

[image: Paste JSON As Classes]

```
public class FloorplanItem
{
    public string Class { get; set; }
    public NodeDataArray[] NodeDataArray { get; set; }
    public object[] LinkDataArray { get; set; }
}

public class NodeDataArray
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Loc { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialization seems to work perfectly (notice I have fixed the property names to obey the common naming guidelines).

[image: Watch]