# ASP.NET Web API - XML in camelcase

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, xml-serialization

We are using Web API with MVC 4, and are required to have our request/responses in camel case.

We have done that for JSON with the following code:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().Single();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

The same code unfortunately doesn't work for the `XmlMediaTypeFormatter`.

What would be the most elegant workaround to format XML in camel case?

Comment: If you splatter the appropriate XmlAttributes on your classes and their properties the XmlSerializer should respect them and serialize the XML as you'd prefer. Not As clean or easy as the Json way but it may be a resonable solution nonetheless checkout this link for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also checkout this answer as an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/22493313/1370442

Comment: Both XmlSeralizer and XmlFormatter have a broad range of trouble that I severely recommend not using of them and just stick on Json serializes facilities such as Json.net or ServiceStack tools.

Answer (score 5):

Solution 1 : Using XmlSerializer

If you need to match an existing XML schema ( in your case like using camel case. ) You should use XmlSerializer class to have more control over the resulting XML.
To use XmlSerializer you need to set below configuration in global.asax file or constructor of your API controller class.

```
var xml = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter;
xml.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

After making this change you can add [DataContract] and [DataMember] for your entities which will affect XML result.

```
[DataContract(Name = "USER")]
public class User
{
    [DataMember(Name = "FIRSTNAME")]
    public string FirstName;    

    [DataMember(Name = "LASTNAME")]
    public string LastName;
}
```

Solution 2 : Creating custom XML Formatter class

You should develop your own Media Formatter class and set it as a default XML formatter.It will take long time and effort than solution 1. 
To be able to create a custom media formatter class please see below link.

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters

Comment: It's unbelievable that nobody made solution 2 open source :(
I tried last year to copy the formatter from Microsoft, but it had too many dependencies.